# FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean installFormatters Method Gone

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm upgrading a Spring 3.2 app to Spring 4.2 and discovered the hard way that the installFormatters() method of FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean was removed in 4.2.0 (I upgraded my maven POM to the current most recent version, 4.2.6.RELEASE).

So, I have this class:

```
public class ApplicationFormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean extends FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean {

    @Override
    protected void installFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {

        super.setRegisterDefaultFormatters(true);

        registry.addFormatterForFieldAnnotation(new AnnotationFormatterFactory1());
        registry.addFormatterForFieldAnnotation(new AnnotationFormatterFactory2());
        // more of the same
    }
}
```

Is there an easy upgrade path here?

Jason

Comment: Is this for MVC or for the generic case? In the first case extend `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` and simply implement `addFormatters` in the other case create a `FormatterRegistrar` and register that with the normal `FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean`.